# Encoding issue while converting text file to resx file using powershell cmd

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, resx

I tried to convert the text file to resx file using powershell command as below,

```
Resgen myFile.txt myFile.resx
```

myFile.txt file consist of German language.

For example: text file consist of “Längsseitenzufuhr” word.

After converted to resx file, it consist the word “Längsseitenzufuhr”  as “L�ngsseitenzufuhr” in resx file.

“ä” not supporting in resx file.

I think its encoding issue.

Also i tried by changing the text file encoding as utf-8. But same issue happening.

Is there any way to get correct word in resx?

Comment: Open myFile.txt in notepad and then save it as a new file with the "unicode" encoding option. Try running resgen against the new file

Comment: Thanks now working..

Answer (score 0):

As a German i know this problem.  We have an international notation for our language specific characters.  Here the List:

```
ä = ae
ö = oe
ü = ue
ß = ss  (exists as lower case only)
Ä = Ae
Ö = Oe
Ü = Ue
```

If possible just replace the German characters on this way, it is allowed in our language.

---

I found some articles like [this here](http://forums.asp.net/t/245128.aspx) to solve the problem on a technical way.  To convert the file to UTF-8 seems to right.